# Kubuntu Wrong Date Locale

Tags: kubuntu, locale

Kubuntu 23.04

Issue: the date in the taskbar and **sometimes** in some places in the settings is displayed in the wrong locale. I live in Georgia (not the US state). I tried many many times to modify the `locale` file located in `/etc/default`. I did it by running `sudo nano locale` while in that folder. I don't think I made a mistake somewhere, because currently `locale` looks like this:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Nonetheless, `echo $LC_TIME` still returns `ka_GE.UTF-8`​ for some reason.​

I also tried the following:

1. `sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8​`
2. `sudo localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_US.utf8` (I just copied the command I found, I don't know if "utf8" without the hyphen is a typo or not)​
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and then updated the en_US.UTF-8 or whatever, I don't know

**UPDATE**: output of `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ka_GE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Do you possibly have a `~/.pam_environment` file? If you have, you can delete it since you are using Kubuntu. (It was probably created when you used some other Ubuntu flavor.)

Comment: Nope, `No such file or directory`. This was a clean install, Kubuntu straight away.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe the KDE settings can explain it: *Settings -> System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Region & Language*

Comment: It says "American English" everywhere.

Comment: Then I still think you have a `~/.pam_environment` file. The `~` means your `$HOME` directory, and the dot makes the file "hidden".

Comment: Btw, did you relogin after having changed `/etc/default/locale`?

Comment: I'll look for it. By the way, while trying to locate this `.pam_environment` folder, I ran `ls -l` and months are displayed in Georgian there, which is, again, odd.

Comment: Yes, I did relogin, restart and whatnot.

Comment: Wow, you were right! There is a `.pam_environment` folder. I see it now after I ran `ls -a`. How to delete it?

Comment: It's not a folder, it's a file. `rm ~/.pam_environment`

Comment: Absolutely amazing, it worked! If you write an answer instead of the comment, I'll make it accepted as the best, if you want.

Comment: I suggest that you write the answer — it's perfectly fine to answer your own question. ;) And if you do, please include the background, i.e. that you previously used some other desktop environment and then switched to Kubuntu. Because that's the case, isn't it?

Comment: If that's the only possible reason that file was present, then, I guess, that is the case. Although, again, I don't remember anything else, I thought what I did was a "clean install".

Comment: If it was a clean Kubuntu install, the presence of that file is a mystery. But well, if you installed a tool named *Language Support* and made changes via that tool, it would explain it. *Language Support* is not included in Kubuntu, since it does not play well with the KDE way to handle regional settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the `.pam_environment` file, located in the `$HOME` directory (`~/.pam_environment`). Apparently, that file was probably created when I used some other Ubuntu flavor and then switched to Kubuntu.

Run the following command to remove it:

```
rm ~/.pam_environment
```

Make sure to relogin after that.